# Preventing an arbitrary block from being displayed on two different pages?

Tags: page-breaking

I have a collection of concert entries; two such entries are displayed below:

```
\textbf{Modest Mouse, Jimmy Eat World, Angels and Airwaves}\\
\textit{LIVE105 Not So Silent Night}\\
Bill Graham Civic Auditorium\\
San Francisco, CA\\
12/7/2007\\

\textbf{Buckethead, That 1 Guy}\\
Fox Theatre\\
Redwood City, CA\\
11/21/2008\\
```

I want to force each separate concert entry to be on the same page -- that is, I don't want, say, `12/7/2007` to spill over to page 2 if the `Modest Mouse` concert entry just so happens to be at the bottom of page 1.

I've tried wrapping each block in `samepage` tags, like so:

```
\begin{samepage}
\textbf{Modest Mouse, Jimmy Eat World, Angels and Airwaves}\\
\textit{LIVE105 Not So Silent Night}\\
Bill Graham Civic Auditorium\\
San Francisco, CA\\
12/7/2007\\
\end{samepage}
```

However, this didn't work.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use a `tabular` structure:

```
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  \textbf{Modest Mouse, Jimmy Eat World, Angels and Airwaves} \\
  \textit{LIVE105 Not So Silent Night} \\
  Bill Graham Civic Auditorium \\
  San Francisco, CA \\
  12/7/2007
\end{tabular}
```

If your titles are wider than the text block, then you might be interested in a `{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}}` column specification.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a `minipage`. A `minipage` won't allow page breaks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \textbf{Modest Mouse, Jimmy Eat World, Angels and Airwaves}\par
    \textit{LIVE105 Not So Silent Night}\par
    Bill Graham Civic Auditorium\par
    San Francisco, CA\par
    12/7/2007
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Same is true for a `\parbox`.